# Python: "TypeError: __str__ returned non-string" but still prints to output?

Tags: python, return, typeerror, return-value, nonetype

I have this piece of code which creates a new note. When I try to print, I get the following error even though it prints the output:

```
Error:
C:\Python27\Basics\OOP\formytesting>python notebook.py
Memo=This is my first memo, Tag=example
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "notebook.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(firstnote)
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

note.py:

```
import datetime

class Note:
    def __init__(self, memo, tags):
        self.memo = memo
        self.tags = tags
        self.creation_date = datetime.date.today()
    
    def __str__(self):
        print('Memo={0}, Tag={1}').format(self.memo, self.tags)
                    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    firstnote = Note('This is my first memo','example')
    print(firstnote)
```

Answer (score 102):

Method [__str__](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) should return string, not print.

```
def __str__(self):
    return 'Memo={0}, Tag={1}'.format(self.memo, self.tags)
```

Answer (score 58):

You can also surround the output with str(). I had this same problem because my model had the following (as a simplified example):

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.pressid
```

Where pressid was an IntegerField type object. Django (and python in general) expects a string for a **str** function, so returning an integer causes this error to be thrown.

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.pressid)
```

That solved the problems I was encountering on the Django management side of the house. Hope it helps with yours.

Comment: This is what I need! How to save this answer for future reference...>???

Answer (score 16):

The problem that you are facing is :
TypeError : **str** returned non-string (type NoneType)

Here you have to understand the **str** function's working:
the **str** fucntion,although is mostly used to print values but actually is designed to return a string,not to print one.
In your class **str** function is calling the print directly while it is returning nothing ,that explains your error output.Since our formatted string is built, and since our function returns nothing, the None value is used.
This was the explaination for your error

You can solve this problem by using the return in **str** function like:
*simply returnig the string value instead of printing it

```
 class Summary(models.Model):
   book = models.ForeignKey(Book,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
   summary = models.TextField(max_length=600)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.summary
```

but if the value you are returning in not of string type then you can do like this to return string value from your **str**  function

*typeconverting the value to string that your **str** function returns

```
class Summary(models.Model):
   book = models.ForeignKey(Book,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
   summary = models.TextField(max_length=600)

   def __str__(self):
       return str(self.summary)
            `
```

Answer (score 3):

In the Model's `__str__` method, you are returning a value which is `null`.

For example:

```py
class X(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), null=True, blank=True, 
    max_length=150)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(_('Date of birth'), null=True, blank=True)
    street = models.CharField(_('Street'), max_length=150, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name # here the value of name field might be null, so the
```

error is showing.

Correct `__str__` method will be:

```py
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Try this:

```
def __str__(self):
    return f'Memo={self.memo}, Tag={self.tags}'
```

Comment: There is no reason to put the `str` constructor around the f-string (definitionally, it's already a `str`).

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same problem, in my case, was because i was returned a digit:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.code
```

str is waiting for a str, not another.

now work good with:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

where name is a STRING.

Answer (score 0):

I,m newbie at Django.
But I share my experience because solved the same case.

My case is that, Someday(no memory) changed(added) some field(memo)'s attribute to null=True. but I totally forgot that my model.py as following.

```
def __str__(self):
    if self is not None:
        return self.author.memo
```

So I edited the return value to some other field. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some null value in your table. Enter to mysql and delete null value in table.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below in Django Admin:

> TypeError: **str** returned non-string (type NoneType)

When I defined `name` field which accepts a `None` value as shown below, then I saved a `None` value in Django Admin:

```py
# "models.py"

class Person(models.Model):                            # Here
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

So, I replaced `self.name` with `str(self.name)` as shown below, then the error was solved:

```py
# "models.py"

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name) # Here
```