# What is wrong with this code python classes and objects

Tags: pycharm

i have a problem where if i type 3 or more characters in pycharm it lags madly. i uninstalled the application and will try installing to see if that fixes the problem + i was in the middle of writing some code. can someone copy my code and paste it on his pycharm to see if it works. if not, can someone tell me what the problem is. probably problems i am new to python
my code:

## there is a problem with indentation when i post so please correct it before running

class bank_account:

```
def __init__(self, account_number,name,opening_balance,type_of_account):


    self.account_number = account_number

    self.name = name

    self.opening_balance = opening_balance

    self.type_of_account = type_of_account

amount_of_money = opening_balance

def __str__(self):

    print('account number: ', account_number)

    print('name: ',name)

    print("opening balance: ", opening balance)

    print('type of account: ',type_of_account)

def deposit(amount):

    global amount_of_money

    amount_of_money += amount

def withdraw(amount):

    global amount_of_money

    amount_of_money -=amount

def get_balance():

    global amount_of_money

    return str(amount_of_money) + '$'
```

acc1 = bank_account('66666666666666', 'mike',1000,'deposit')

acc1.deposit(250)

acc1.get_balance()

print(acc1)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not good to say the least. PyCharm should tell you if there any problems before it runs. I'm not sure if you are running on a potato that it lags.

Here are the mistakes I found:

- `opening balance` should be `opening_balance`
- indentation errors
- all class functions should have `self` as a first argument
- don't use `global` to access class variables. Use `self.`
- PEP-8 violations that can be corrected with pressing `CTRL+ALT+L` on your keyboard
- `__str__` should not print. It should rather return an `str`
- Edit: classes should follow CamelCaps conventions
- Not an error but I suggest sticking with either single or double quotes to encapsulate strings. Everyone should at least be consistent with themselves.

There are probably some logic mistakes but that depends on what you want to do with the class.

```py
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self, account_number, name, opening_balance, type_of_account):
        self.account_number = account_number

        self.name = name

        self.opening_balance = opening_balance

        self.type_of_account = type_of_account

        self.amount_of_money = opening_balance

    def __str__(self):
        result = "account number: " + str(self.account_number)
        result += "\nname: " + str(self.name)
        result += "\nopening balance: " + str(self.opening_balance)
        result += "\ncurrent balance: " + str(self.amount_of_money)
        result += "\ntype of account: " + str(self.type_of_account)
        return result

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.amount_of_money += amount

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        self.amount_of_money -= amount

    def get_balance(self):
        return str(self.amount_of_money) + "$"


acc1 = BankAccount("66666666666666", "mike", 1000, "deposit")

acc1.deposit(250)

print(acc1.get_balance())

print(acc1)
```

I highly recommend following a tutorial series on Python. You won't be blundering about for hours not knowing what to do. [This one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YYXdXT2l-Gg&list=PL-osiE80TeTt2d9bfVyTiXJA-UTHn6WwU) by Corey Schafer seemed very professional to me and I learnt Flask from one of his tutorials.

If PyCharm is too heavy duty for you computer, there are many other lighter editors such as Atom or Sublime Text.

Comment: I'm actually new to programming and I am still having so many problems with classes    Thanks for your response!!!

Comment: oh yeah what do you mean __str__ should not print it should return. will it make an error

Comment: Yes, it will make an error. ```__str__ ``` is a built-in function that should take in nothing but it should return a string describing the object. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871221/python-typeerror-str-returned-non-string-but-still-prints-to-output).