# I need to display statistics as a number

Tags: django

I just started learning django and ran into a problem
when using
def **str**(self):
return self.timetable
the date in the admin panel is displayed as numbers, but it gives the error ''**str** returned non-string (type datetime.time)''
[when replacing **str** with something else, the time is displayed like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hz5i9.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: "TypeError: \_\_str\_\_ returned non-string" but still prints to output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871221/python-typeerror-str-returned-non-string-but-still-prints-to-output)

Answer (score 0):

You need to format datetime.time object to string, like this

```
from datetime import datetime
current = datetime.now().time()  # datetime.time object
string_time = current.strftime("%H:%M:%S")  # this value is what you need
```

You can change the format if you need

> https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior